# Google app engine/GAE egress traffic monitoring

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

How can we monitor the Google app engine (egress)traffic like the VMs instance ?
since  The GAE of Google Cloud Free Tier has 1 GB of egress per day for Standard Environment.

would like to monitor my app egress traffic to budget myself. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

“Out Bandwidth” SKU and the “Network Sent Bytes” Metric in the dashboard can confirm the network egress price and billing. The `appengine.googleapis.com/system/network/sent_bytes_count` is the metric which provides the Delta count of outgoing network bandwidth, sampled every 60 seconds.

[App Engine standard has an outgoing network traffic cost](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#network-resources-in-the-standard-environment) of about  $0.12/Gb and [Out Bandwidth](https://cloud.google.com/skus?currency=USD&filter=app%20engine) is 0.00 USD (Free) per gibibyte, for 0 to 1 gibibyte, per day per project and 0.12 USD per gibibyte, for 1 gibibyte and above, per day per project

If you look at the Network usage on Metrics Explorer you can find further information about the usage and the tendency that will match the billing made for Out Bandwidth.
On actively looking into your request to see if there is a way to see App engine egress that would correlate with the increase in billing. I'm trying to figure out the settings/parameters you would need to set in order to see the total accumulated bytes sent out by app engine

1. Go to metrics explorer in cloud console
2. For "Select a Metric" : GAE -> System -> Sent bytes
3. At the top of the chart be sure to select "1M"(1 Month) & change
   "line chart" to "Stacked Bar Chart" in the dropdown <--- very
   important
4. In the "How do you want to view that data?" section put in the
   following:

   - Groupby : Projectid
   - Aggregator: Max
   - Minimum Alignment Period : 1 day
5. Under "show advanced advanced options" section put the following :
   Aligner: Sum
6. Leave the rest as is.

Note : Leave the rest as is, just remember to set the chart to 1 month and a stacked bar chart.

Also, this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/network-pricing#:%7E:text=the%20other%20VM.-,Egress%20traffic,-Traffic%20leaving%20a) talks about the scenarios and different multiple sources from where you are charged for egress traffic and it's not always only GAE.